# Check if two sequences contain the same number in xpath

Tags: xpath

Im looking for a xpath function that compares two sequences and checks if the any of the values in sequence one is contained in sequence two.

Example:

Seq1: 5, 1, 8, 0 and seq2: 9, 4, 3 should be false

Seq1: 5, 7, 8 and seq2: 0, 2, 5 should give true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPath 2.0 has sequences and comparison of sequences with `=` that does just what you ask for so doing `$seq1 = $seq2` is all you need in XPath 2.0.

XPath 1.0 does not have sequences so you will need to explain in more detail how your input looks if you are asking about XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

http://sources.redhat.com/ml/xsl-list/2000-08/msg00355.html

eg `count($set1[count(.|$set2)=count($set2)])>0`